# Select matching date

Tags: sql-server

I have a Sales Order table and a Sales Order History table to store changes. The tables look like this:

```
(Sales Order)
SO_ID | OrderName | Quantity
10    | Order A   | 150
20    | Order B   | 150

(Sales Order History)
ID | SO_ID | Quantity | Change_Date
1  | 10    | 100      | 10/05/2015
2  | 20    | 50       | 13/05/2015
3  | 10    | 500      | 17/05/2015
4  | 20    | 200      | 23/05/2015
```

Now I want to create a report to show what was the quantity in a specific date. For example, for the SO_ID 10 the result for the day 12/05/2015 should be:

```
SO_ID | Old_Quantity | Current_Quantity
10    | 100          | 150
```

How to write a query to get this result?

Comment: Is there anything you've tried so far?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JoelC, using distinct I was able to get the OrderId, but it didn't solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy with a CTE. This will find the last entry in the `SalesOrderHistory` table as of a reference date:

```
DECLARE @refDate date = '12/05/2015'

;WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT      s.SO_ID,
                    Old_Quantity     = h.Quantity,
                    Current_Quantity = s.Quantity,
                    rowNumber = row_number() over (partition by s.SO_ID order by Change_Date DESC)
        FROM        SalesOrder          s
        INNER JOIN  SalesOrderHistory   h   ON s.SO_ID = h.SO_ID
        WHERE       h.Change_Date <= @refDate
    )

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rowNumber = 1
```

There's a caveat though: the query won't work if the sales order does not have an entry in the History table. Not sure if you want that.